# Code "not responding" in Excel 2013. Convert to formulas/new code

Tags: excel, vba

I have code below that works in Excel 2010.

I upgraded to 2013 and now get a not responding issue.

I tried replacing this code with 16 formulas, EE2:ET6141. I found this inefficient, time consuming, and uses much memory.

**formula to replace my code:**

`IF(AND(OR($BM:$BM="value1",$BM:$BM="value2",$BM:$BM="value3"),$BN:$BN<>"Excel",$BN:$BN<>"ITS"),$AT:$AT*(IFNA(VLOOKUP(EE$1&$S:$S,EQ_Shocks!E:F,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(EE$1&"OTHERS",EQ_Shocks!E:F,2,FALSE))-1),"")`

Logic something like:
for each row where A1 = Stackoverflow, BM = value1 or value2 or value3  and BN not in Excel and not in ITS. then get value from EQ_shocks sheet.

**code**

It gets the not responding error at this line `If thisEqShocks(1, 1) = "#EMPTY" Then`  I put a breakpoint at the `end if`  and it takes long or not responding trying to loop through this big if statement.

I also notice this at the for loop, `For thisScen = 1 To UBound(stressScenMapping, 1)`, takes long to respond through breakpoint `Next thisScen` I would say it is safe to say its this part of the code.

```
Public Sub oldcode() 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long, thisScen As Long, nRows As Long, nCols As Long
    Dim stressWS As Worksheet

    Set stressWS = Worksheets("EQ_Shocks")
    Unprotect_Tab ("EQ_Shocks")
    nRows = lastWSrow(stressWS)
    nCols = lastWScol(stressWS)

    Dim readcols() As Long
    ReDim readcols(1 To nCols)

    For i = 1 To nCols
        readcols(i) = i
    Next i

    Dim eqShocks() As Variant
    eqShocks = colsFromWStoArr(stressWS, readcols, False)

    'read in database columns
    Dim dataWs As Worksheet
    Set dataWs = Worksheets("database")

    nRows = lastRow(dataWs)
    nCols = lastCol(dataWs)

    Dim dataCols() As Variant
    Dim riskSourceCol As Long
    riskSourceCol = getWScolNum("RiskSource", dataWs)

    ReDim readcols(1 To 4)
    readcols(1) = getWScolNum("RiskReportProductType", dataWs)
    readcols(2) = getWScolNum("Fair Value (USD)", dataWs)
    readcols(3) = getWScolNum("Source Currency of the CUSIP that is denominated in", dataWs)
    readcols(4) = riskSourceCol

    dataCols = colsFromWStoArr(dataWs, readcols, True)

    'read in scenario mappings
    Dim mappingWS As Worksheet
    Set mappingWS = Worksheets("mapping_ScenNames")

    Dim stressScenMapping() As Variant
    ReDim readcols(1 To 2): readcols(1) = 1: readcols(2) = 2
    stressScenMapping = colsFromWStoArr(mappingWS, readcols, False, 2) 'include two extra columns to hold column number for IR and CR shocks

    For i = 1 To UBound(stressScenMapping, 1)
        stressScenMapping(i, 3) = getWScolNum(stressScenMapping(i, 2), dataWs)
        If stressScenMapping(i, 2) <> "NA" And stressScenMapping(i, 3) = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Could not find " & stressScenMapping(i, 2) & " column in database")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim readcols(1 To 4): readcols(1) = 1: readcols(2) = 2: readcols(3) = 3: readcols(4) = 4
    stressScenMapping = filterOut(stressScenMapping, 2, "NA", readcols)

    'calculate stress and write to database
    Dim thisEqShocks() As Variant

    Dim keepcols() As Long
    ReDim keepcols(1 To UBound(eqShocks, 2))
    For i = 1 To UBound(keepcols)
        keepcols(i) = i
    Next i

    Dim thisCurrRow As Long

    For thisScen = 1 To UBound(stressScenMapping, 1)

        thisEqShocks = filterIn(eqShocks, 2, stressScenMapping(thisScen, 1), keepcols)

        If thisEqShocks(1, 1) = "#EMPTY" Then
            For i = 2 To nRows
                If dataCols(i, 4) <> "Excel" And dataCols(i, 4) <> "OBI" And (dataCols(i, 1) = "value1" Or dataCols(i, 1) = "value2") Then
                    dataWs.Cells(i, stressScenMapping(thisScen, 3)).Value = "No shock found"
                End If
            Next i
        Else                                     'calculate shocks
            Call quicksort(thisEqShocks, 3, 1, UBound(thisEqShocks, 1))
            For i = 2 To nRows
                If dataCols(i, 4) <> "Excel" And dataCols(i, 4) <> "ITS" And (dataCols(i, 1) = "value1" Or dataCols(i, 1) = "value2" Or dataCols(i, 1) = "value3") Then
                    thisCurrRow = findInArrCol(dataCols(i, 3), 3, thisEqShocks)
                    If thisCurrRow = 0 Then      'could not find currency so use generic shock
                        thisCurrRow = findInArrCol("OTHERS", 3, thisEqShocks)
                    End If
                    If thisCurrRow = 0 Then
                        dataWs.Cells(i, stressScenMapping(thisScen, 3)).Value = "No shock found"
                    Else
                        dataWs.Cells(i, stressScenMapping(thisScen, 3)).Value = Replace(dataCols(i, 2), "-", 0) * (thisEqShocks(thisCurrRow, 4) - 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If

    Next thisScen
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

adding function quicksort

```
Sub quicksort(ByRef arr() As Variant, ByVal sortCol As Long, ByVal left As Long, ByVal right As Long)

    If right > left Then
        Dim pivotIndex As Long
        pivotIndex = left + Int((right - left) / 2)

        Dim pivotIndexNew As Long
        pivotIndexNew = partition(arr, sortCol, left, right, pivotIndex)
        Call quicksort(arr, sortCol, left, pivotIndexNew - 1)
        Call quicksort(arr, sortCol, pivotIndexNew + 1, right)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you maybe `F8` through your code and let us know about when it freezes? This is a lot of homebrew code (as in lots of UDFs) to trace through for this question

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 , it is this if loop, `If thisEqShocks(1, 1) = "#EMPTY" Then` or even at the for loop. `For thisScen = 1 To UBound(stressScenMapping, 1)`

Comment: Are you trying to compare it to a string value of "#Empty"? "#" may be working as a wildcard representing any digit 0-9.

Comment: @Mistella , dont think so, what would you recommend doing here instead? Also this code works in seconds in excel 2010, so its not really the functionality that needs a change but more optimization.

Comment: is your goal there to check for that exact string or is it to check that the cell is empty? I dont use formulas often but i dont think ive seen one resolve to `#EMPTY` before

Comment: i've seen `#REF!`, `#VALUE!`, `#DIV/0!`, `#NAME!`, `#NULL!` ... but i dont think "empty" - still, it's possible i just havent seen it, in which case maybe this? will help https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-iserror-function.html

Comment: Also, when a cell formula results in an error value, I'm not sure the contents get interpreted as a string. However, there is a VBA function `IsEmpty()` (?)  that may work equivalently.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I dont think `#empty` is possible error either. It code is looking for string `#EMPTY`.

Comment: @Mistella okay I figured it out, it is looking for string `#EMPTY`

Comment: #EMPTY is likely a place holder to make it obvious to the user, as such, it should be a string, not an xl constant or worksheet error.  That shouldn't be a problem unless OP expected different  behavior or made a silly mistake.  One thing i noticed, at both places where it reportedly hangs, there are calls to outside functions/procedures.  Can we be certain the problem isn't there.   I can imagine the upgrade tweaking something we can't readily spot, might want to export the project and bring it into a clean workbook.

Comment: I have this `quicksort` function , i shall post that aswell. but when I run through the code it doesnt usually hang there and reference this function many times throughout.

Comment: any help for me?

Comment: You have two separate "For i = 2 To nRows". Do you find that both go very slow or just one of them and if so which one?

Comment: Have you thought to check for differences in referenced libraries between the excel versions - similar to this: https://excel.tips.net/T003340_Automatically_Changing_References_to_VBA_Libraries.html - usually you will get an error "Can't find project or library" on load, but in some cases I've seen a library is the same from one excel version to another, but a change in behavior affects the code in a negative way.

Comment: @tremor  thanks Ill try. Its pretty frustrating that this is working perfect in 2010 and 2013 it just freezes. Its definately not my pc as its pretty good performance wise. And I dont have the option to revert to 2010 or upgrade or patch my 2013.

Comment: @tremor can you recommend something for 2010 and 2013 auto reference code?